# JavaScript - Is passing undefined as a parameter the same as leaving it out?

Tags: javascript, function

Pretty straightforward question. For example, are these equivalent?

`window.open('http://someurl.com')`

`window.open('http://someurl.com', undefined)`

Part of me suspects that it might depend on the function itself, but I'm not sure.

Comment: For all normal applications, yes. However, e.g. for non-arrow functions it is possible to detect the difference, e.g. with the `arguments` object. Therefore, it is not guaranteed to always produce the same behavior. It just behaves the same normally, because stereotypical tests just check for `undefined`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: In the vast majority of cases, passing `undefined` is equivalent to leaving the argument out.

However, within a function, you can differentiate between an omitted argument and one that was passed as `undefined`. While I would never recommend using that distinction to change behavior, you can see the difference between the two if you access the special `arguments` variable within your function:

```js
function logNumArgs() {
  console.log(arguments.length)
}

logNumArgs() // 0
logNumArgs(undefined, undefined) // 2
```

Note: the `arguments` variable is only accessible on non-arrow functions!

[MDN - Arguments Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments#:%7E:text=You%20can%20refer%20to%20a,first%20entry%27s%20index%20at%200%20.&text=You%20can%20use%20arguments.length,the%20function%20was%20called%20with.)

Comment: I ran into this issue because `new Date()` returns the current date/time but `new Date(undefined)` returns an Invalid Date.  I have a variable that I want to pass to Date that either simulates no value being passed or an actual value.  Since I can't do that I have to invoke Date twice on two sides of a ternary operator, which makes me **cross**